# Can't add or delete friend in Steam

Tags: steam

I'm trying to add a friend in Steam but it doesn't allow me because my friend slots are full. I am trying to delete one of my friends to open a slot but it doesn't work. It gives an error saying that it failed to delete the friend.

Comment: Have you tried removing them from both your client and from their profile pages?

Comment: Yes I have tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your Steam Family Sharing is active. Lot of functions is disabled while Family Sharing is enabled.

If isn't that you need to contact steam support.

Or just up a level to open 5 more friend slot.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your account is limited?

This means you didn't bought something for at least 5$ in the steam market.

You can add no one and other things are limited. If your friend has got an unlimited one he can add you, because with a limited account you are still allowed to accept friend requests.

You can check [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3330-IAGK-7663) what you can do with a limited account and things you can not do.